# How to create a substitution cipher in which the encryption alphabet changes everytime?

Tags: java, encryption, substitution, caesar-cipher, alphabet

```
public static String encrypt(String plaintext, String encryptalpha) {
        char[] alpha = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
}
```

So the above is the normal alphabet and I need to compare it to the alphabet that the user enters, but this alphabet will be different each time, so how would I compare the two alphabets as I cant put the encryption alphabet in a char array because it'll be different every time.

I know that I need to have two char arrays in order to compare both alphabets and encrypt the plain text, below is the for a loop. I will use it to compare each character of both strings.

```
for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
```

Comment: IMO, you should update your question and better describe what are you trying to accomplish? For example, I am not sure why you need to compare alphabets?! (In the Caeser cipher algorithm the alphabets are the same. It is only shifted.)
Also, the for loops are incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

1. Let's not call this 'encryption'. It might give someone the entirely wrong idea that this would actually protect anything. Do not overpromise and underdeliver. The right word is 'encoding'.
2. You can still put a user-controlled sequence in a char array, just, you can't put the *contents* of the char array directly in your source code.

For example, if the idea is that the user enters a 26-length string on the command line, and that becomes the new substitution, you could e.g. do:

```
char[] substitution;
System.out.print("Enter the substitution string: ");
String userInput = scanner.next();
if (userInput.length() != 26) throw new InvalidInputException("Must be 26 characters precisely");
substitution = userInput.toCharArray();
```

Now you still have a char array, it's just provided by the user via command prompt instead of hardcoding the contents in your source file.

3. No, you don't need that for loop.

Characters are represented by the computer as a number. That's because it's a computer: It's all numbers (in fact, it's all bits) if you dig down deep enough.

For characters, there's this gigantic table that maps a number to the character that number represents, it's called 'the unicode table'. A very early version of this is called the ASCII table (it's many many decades old), and it is far smaller. The unicode table is a superset: Every number that the ASCII table maps (and it only maps the numbers 32 through 127, it's a very small table) map to the same number in unicode, and all the letters are in the ASCII table (and therefore, the unicode table, which java strings are actually based on).

That means 'a' is just a number. Specifically, it's [The number 97](https://www.asciitable.com).

The ASCII table lists the letters in alphabetical order. So, 'b' is 98, 'c' is 99, and so on.

Thus, all you really need if you have a `char[]` that lists the substitutions, is to 'map' the letter you have, say, 'c', to the right 'spot' in the substitution char array, which is index 2 (java is 0-based, so `substitution[0]` is the first letter, i.e. it tells you what to replace 'a' with, `substitution[1]` tells what to replace 'b' with, and `substitution[2]` tells you what to replace 'c' with.

So, how do we turn 'c' into '2'?

Easy. Subtract 97. That's all you need to do. To make your code more readable, subtract `'a'` (As I just said, all characters are just number. `'a'` and `97` are **identical** as far as the bits are concerned.

Thus:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
s.useDelimiter("\\R"); // always do this.

char[] substitution = ....; // see snippet above
System.out.println("What string shall I encode for you?: ");
String toEncode = s.next();
char[] toEncodeChars = toEncode.toCharArray();
char[] encoded = new char[toEncodeChars.length];
for (int i = 0; i < toEncodeChars.length; i++) {
    char c = toEncodeChars[i];
    if (c < 'a' && c > 'z') {
        // we cannot encode this. Just let it go unchanged, I guess.
        encoded[i] = c;
    } else {
       int indexInSubstitution = c - 'a';
       char substitutionChar = substitution[indexInSubstitution];
       encoded[i] = substitutionChar;
    }
}
```

NB: Scanner is by default not great for parsing command input. Always run `useDelimiter("\\R")`, once immediately after creating the scanner. Now, never use `nextLine`; to read some user input, call the appropriate `nextX` method, where just `next()` reads the entire line. This avoids the mess with newlines and combining `nextLine()` and e.g. `nextInt()`.

See? No need for a double for loop, you can just do a look up.